# Persistent error when installing package terra - testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location

Tags: compilation, terra

When trying to install terra like so

`Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")`

`remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")`

It starts to compile the package, resulting in a lot of output in the console, but ending in the error (error at bottom):

```
lhdf5 -lsz -lpng16 -lpng -lpoppler -llcms2 -lfreetype -lharfbuzz -lfreetype -llz4 -lpcre2-8 -lpcre -lcurl -lrtmp -lssl -lssh2 -lidn2 -lunistring -liconv -lgcrypt -lcrypto -lgpg-error -lws2_32 -ltiff -llzma -ljpeg -lz -lcfitsio -lzstd -lwebpdecoder -lwebp -lsbml-static -lgeotiff -lproj -lsqlite3 -lbz2 -lcrypt32 -lwldap32 -lsecur32 -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/PackagesR/00LOCK-terra/00new/terra/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
in method for 'sds' with signature 'x="stars"': no definition for class "stars"
in method for 'sds' with signature 'x="stars_proxy"': no definition for class "stars_proxy"
in method for 'svc' with signature 'x="sf"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"stars","SpatRasterDataset"': no definition for class "stars"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"ggmap","SpatRaster"': no definition for class "ggmap"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"sf","SpatRaster"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"sf","SpatVector"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"sfc","SpatVector"': no definition for class "sfc"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"sfg","SpatVector"': no definition for class "sfg"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"XY","SpatVector"': no definition for class "XY"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"im","SpatRaster"': no definition for class "im"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"SpatVector","Spatial"': no definition for class "Spatial"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"Spatial","SpatVector"': no definition for class "Spatial"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"SpatialGrid","SpatRaster"': no definition for class "SpatialGrid"
in method for 'coerce' with signature '"SpatialPixels","SpatRaster"': no definition for class "SpatialPixels"
in method for 'crs' with signature '"sf"': no definition for class "sf"
Creating a generic function for 'ncol' from package 'base' in package 'terra'
in method for 'distance' with signature 'x="SpatRaster",y="sf"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'ext' with signature 'x="sf"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'ext' with signature 'x="bbox"': no definition for class "bbox"
in method for 'ext' with signature 'x="Extent"': no definition for class "Extent"
in method for 'ext' with signature 'x="Raster"': no definition for class "Raster"
in method for 'ext' with signature 'x="Spatial"': no definition for class "Spatial"
in method for 'extract' with signature 'x="SpatRaster",y="sf"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'mask' with signature 'x="SpatRaster",mask="sf"': no definition for class "sf"
Creating a generic function for 'unserialize' from package 'base' in package 'terra'
Creating a generic function for 'readRDS' from package 'base' in package 'terra'
in method for 'lines' with signature 'x="leaflet"': no definition for class "leaflet"
in method for 'points' with signature 'x="leaflet"': no definition for class "leaflet"
in method for 'rast' with signature 'x="stars"': no definition for class "stars"
in method for 'rast' with signature 'x="stars_proxy"': no definition for class "stars_proxy"
in method for 'rasterize' with signature 'x="sf",y="SpatRaster"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'show' with signature '"Rcpp_SpatDataFrame"': no definition for class "Rcpp_SpatDataFrame"
in method for 'show' with signature '"Rcpp_SpatCategories"': no definition for class "Rcpp_SpatCategories"
in method for 'geomtype' with signature 'x="Spatial"': no definition for class "Spatial"
in method for 'vect' with signature 'x="Spatial"': no definition for class "Spatial"
in method for 'vect' with signature 'x="sf"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'vect' with signature 'x="sfc"': no definition for class "sfc"
in method for 'vect' with signature 'x="XY"': no definition for class "XY"
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/PackagesR/terra'
* restoring previous 'C:/PackagesR/terra'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/CORNVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6Pz2Jn/file1eac467567ab/terra_1.6-44.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Cannot figure out what is going on. Is someone able to provide some insight in how to fix this?

I have the most up to date Rtools, R and RStudio. I also have Rccp installed.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install the development version of "terra" on windows is

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

The version you get is at most a couple of hours behind the github version, but it is already compiled.

To install from github, you need the latest version of RTools. It is also very important that you start with a clean session (no packages loaded, see `sessionInfo()`; and make sure you do not load a prior session when starting your R session.